# Java compile with processors in one command

Tags: java, annotations, compilation

Is there some way to do compilation of both code and processors in the same `javac` run? For example when the source tree contains:

```
a.java   // with annotations
b.java   // processor
c.java   // referrencing files to be generated
```

Can I somehow compile it all with one `javac` invocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Annotation processing is done in a separate round before compilation, at which point b.java would already have to be compiled. You need to separate compile runs. One for the processor, one for the rest.